# Running Docker with ABP Module Template Issue

Tags: docker, abp

I got started with ABP with a project using the module template:

> abp new Sample -t module --no-ui

As I'm not familiar with Docker either, I did not run on Docker at the start and continue coding for the app and all works well.
Now that I have a running app with some functions, I want to get it working with Docker and I'm facing an issue where the container gets started and immediately end with exited with code 1 with no log at all.

Unable to resolve the issue, I then created another solution from the ABP module template and encountered the same issue when I try docker-compose or even docker run individually on a project.
As the docker-compose file and Dockerfile from the ABP module template is not up to date. I made some changes and this is the Dockerfile script that I managed to build after the changes below.

Has anyone encountered the same issue or has any idea why the app container exits with EXITED(1)?

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0-buster-slim AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["host/Sample.IdentityServer/Sample.IdentityServer.csproj", "host/Sample.IdentityServer/"]
COPY ["host/Sample.Host.Shared/Sample.Host.Shared.csproj", "host/Sample.Host.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/Sample.Domain.Shared/Sample.Domain.Shared.csproj", "src/Sample.Domain.Shared/"]
COPY ["src/Sample.Application.Contracts/Sample.Application.Contracts.csproj", "src/Sample.Application.Contracts/"]
RUN dotnet restore "host/Sample.IdentityServer/Sample.IdentityServer.csproj" -nowarn:msb3202,nu1503
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/host/Sample.IdentityServer
RUN dotnet build --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish --no-restore -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Sample.IdentityServer.dll"]
```

Comment: It seems that the files created for containerization seem to be outdated, I opened an issue for it => https://github.com/abpframework/abp/issues/10103

Comment: Thank berkansasmaz. Any idea on the issue I'm facing as to why exited(1) happens?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no idea :(

Answer (score 0):

Module template does not have a runnable project. There are sample host projects to help you develop and test your module.

So basically, you are **dockerizing the test host application**. Normally, you should develop your module and let the end application (the runnable application which uses your module) should be dockerizing. That can be a non tiered app, or tiered angular app etc.

**A sample:** [Abp Account Management](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/modules/account) is a module and it is used by the [application template](https://github.com/abpframework/abp/tree/dev/templates/app/aspnet-core) you create with CLI or web interface. So you need to dockerize the **running application** not the library you are using.

Comment: It does have runnable projects. You can try it out yourself with the command in my question. It will have Sample.HttpApi.Host and Sample.IdentityServer. You can then have a look at the dockerfile and docker-compose file. It is outdated as berkansasmaz has opened an issue on it.